# how to load statically under here JqGrid asp.net mvc action dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-5.2

```
public ActionResult All(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
            {
                var jsonData = new
                {
                    total = 1, // we'll implement later 
                    page = page,
                    records = 100, // implement later 
                    rows = new[]{
                    new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}},
               }
                };
                return Json(jsonData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: What is your error? You should add the jqGrid tag to your question as well.

Comment: i want to convert with dynamically above action ...

Comment: I used `Dictionary<string, object>` to represent the objects on the C# side, then converted it to an object to pass to `Json()`. Again, explain what is not working so people can help you better.